# Magento _searchCriterias cannot be changed

Tags: magento

I'm building a custom search results page, and I have the IDs of all products that have to be included in the results. I want to override the default search criteria, and yes, I can override `$this->_searchCriterias`, but it does not change the results page itself.

This is my custom code of `CatalogSearch/Model/Advanced.php`

```
   public function getSearchCriterias()
    {
        $search = $this->_searchCriterias;

        var_dump($search);

        $search = array();

        if(isset($_GET['productid'])) {
            $value = $this->getIdsFromSearchUrl($_GET['productid']);
            if(is_array($value)){
              foreach($value as $v){
                if(is_numeric($v)){
                  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($v);
                  var_dump($product->getId());
                  $search[] = array('name'=>'Name','value'=>$product->getName());
                }
              }
            } else {
              if(is_numeric($value)){
               $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($value);
               $search[] = array('name'=>'Name','value'=>$product->getName());
              }
            }
        }

        var_dump($search);

        $this->_searchCriterias = $search;

        return $search;
    }
```

Any help appreceated.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand is that you want the site to always include some "featured products", which are not necessarily related to the search term.
I would suggest an alternative method instead of tampering with the search engine logic:

1. Create a block and template for displaying featured products.
2. Add the block to Search engine result page inside the product_list block (under catalogsearch_result_index)
3. Modify list.phtml and echo out the child block you just added.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: No, sorry if it was unclear. I built a custom search engine (a GUI) which returns specific ids to show on the results page.

Comment: Hi Rápli, have you tried modifying getAdvancedResultCollection() and replace it with the collection of product that has the ids returned from you custom search engine?